# ZF Apigility Admin UI set main authentication

Tags: zend-framework, laminas-api-tools

I'm trying to create an authentication in ZF Apigility Admin UI, but I haven't found any information regarding this..

The authentication must be only for Admin UI page (http://host/apigility/ui/)

Maybe someone has links to the documentation/guide how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find anything about authentication, but you can disable development mode by executing the following command from terminal: 
`php public/index.php development disable`